# How to change org-mode tables background color in Spacemacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I want to change how tables look in org-mode. I am running spacemacs master branch on Manjaro i3.

By default, the background color of the table doesn't match the plain text background.

I tried to customize by changing options in customize-group/org-faces/org-tables but I couldn't make it work.

Here is a snapshot of how it look now

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some text to highlight the difference? I'm not sure what difference you are talking about (that may be my bad, old, tired eyes however).

Comment: I can't reproduce that, so it may be spacemacs (which I don't know anything about) or some other customization: e.g. if you open the file with `emacs -Q` you should not have that problem. The `org-table` face just sets the *foreground* color, it does not touch the background.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to modify the background of the org-mode tables, was using the theming layer to modify my theme.

1. Add the `theming` layer to your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`.
2. In the `user-init` section add:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  (setq theming-modifications
        '((gruvbox-dark-soft ;; Your theme name
           (org-table :background "#282828" :foreground "#fe8019")
         ))
    )
)
```

It should work after reloading the configuration and the org-mode buffers.